Troubleshooting WebDriver Binaries Update Issue in Selenium Automation Setup
Encountered compatibility issues with the ChromeDriver binary specified in the repositorymap.xml file for my Selenium automation setup. Despite attempting to update the <filelocation> and <hash> attributes to reflect the latest ChromeDriver version 124.0.6367.202, as recommended in "Mastering Selenium 3.0 Second Edition," the browser session fails to launch, displaying the error message:
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 90. Current browser version is 124.0.6367.202 with binary path C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe

For reference, the repository map being used can be found here.
The structure I modified is as follows:
<driver id="googlechrome">
    <version id="124">
        <bitrate thirtytwobit="true" sixtyfourbit="true">
            <filelocation>https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/125.0.6422.60/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip</filelocation>
            <hash>Updated_Hash_Value</hash>
            <hashtype>sha1</hashtype>
        </bitrate>
    </version>
</driver>

Despite these adjustments, the issue persists, and tests fail with the error:
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.118 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.masteringselenium.BasicIT
[ERROR] googleCheeseExample(com.masteringselenium.BasicIT)  Time elapsed: 1.853 s  <<< FAILURE! 
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 90. Current browser version is 124.0.6367.202 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-AAFER2Q', ip: '172.21.144.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '21'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Seeking guidance on how to effectively update the ChromeDriver binary and resolve this compatibility issue. Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

As of Selenium 4.6, SeleniumManager was added and it automatically takes care of downloading and configuring the appropriate driver for you. So, you no longer need to use a DriverManager or specify the path, etc.
All you need is
String url = "https://www.google.com";

driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(url);

